# Deriving Inverse of Cumulative Distribution function

Tags: normal-distribution, quantiles, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

let $f(x)$ be a probability distribution, and $g(x)$ be the cumulative distribution of that probability distribution (CDF)

By definition, CDF is:

$ g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(x) dx $

**Given $g(x)$, I want to find $f(x)$:**

$f(x)=???$ in terms of $g(x)$, aka the inverse of this integral.

Is analytic solution possible for any f(x)?
Inverse function of a finite integral confuses me.

---

If we assume $f(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} g(x)$, then does the equation balance out?

$ g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{d}{dx} g(x) dx $

$g(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} g(x) $ ???

$g(x)=[g(x)]_x - [g(x)]_{-\infty}$ ???

since $[g(x)]_{-\infty}$ equals to zero???, hence:

$g(x)=[g(x)]_x$???

It feels right and wrong at the same time. It's probably wrong, I'm so confused.

Comment: No, an analytical solution is not always possible. Also note that a CDF outputs values between 0 and 1, so the InverseCDF is only valid for inputs between 0 and 1. See https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InverseCDF.html for some general background.

Comment: I'm struggling to understand which concepts I need to understand. Is it 0) Does analytical inverse of a finite integral exist?  1) How to find analytical inverse of a finite integral?  2) How does it matter that f and g are PDFs or can they be arbitrary functions?  3) Do I need to study the derivation of what things?

Comment: I think this is a good question. I am also interested in learning more about this topic. I suggest you try browsing through StackExchange for similar questions, learn what the best way is to pose questions on this website and ask a new one. StackExchange can be difficult for beginners, as there are many rules etc. But I can assure you that it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 2):

This is the [Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus),

We know that $$\frac{d}{dx} g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \, dt = f(x)$$

---

Using the property that  that integrations are anti-derivatives,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{d}{dt}g(t) \, dt = g(x) - \lim_{t \to -\infty}g(t)
=g(x)\end{align}